# How to retrieve storage info in iOS

Tags: ios, storage

I would like to retrieve the storage information programmatically like capacity, available storage, total number of apps, videos, pics etc.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like WrightsCS answered disk space question.

If you want number of images, check out [`ALAssetsLibrary`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) of the `AssetsLibrary.framework` (you'll have to include this framework in your "Link Binary With Libraries" section of the `Target` settings) and then:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

// get the image assets

ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
NSAssert(library, @"Unable to open ALAssetsLibrary");

NSUInteger __block images = 0;
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                       usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop){
                           NSLog(@"%@", group);
                           images += group.numberOfAssets;
                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                               // update my UI with the number of images
                           });
                       }
                     failureBlock:^(NSError *err){
                         NSLog(@"err=%@", err);
                     }];
```

If you want to access the iTunes library on non-jailbroken devices, check out the [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html), which shows you how to use `MPMediaQuery` (remember to include the `MediaPlayer.framework` in your project), and then:

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
NSAssert(everything, @"Unable to open MPMediaQuery");

iTunesMediaCount = [[everything items] count];
```

I don't know if there's a published API for getting the number of apps. There are solutions for jailbroken devices, but I don't know about the rest of us.

You didn't ask about this, but if you want available RAM (not flash storage, but memory available for apps), you can get it via:

```
#import <mach/mach.h>
#import <mach/mach_host.h>

- (void)determineMemoryUsage
{
    mach_port_t host_port;
    mach_msg_type_number_t host_size;
    vm_size_t pagesize;

    host_port = mach_host_self();
    host_size = sizeof(vm_statistics_data_t) / sizeof(integer_t);
    host_page_size(host_port, &pagesize);        

    vm_statistics_data_t vm_stat;

    if (host_statistics(host_port, HOST_VM_INFO, (host_info_t)&vm_stat, &host_size) != KERN_SUCCESS)
        NSLog(@"Failed to fetch vm statistics");

    /* Stats in bytes */ 
    natural_t mem_used = (vm_stat.active_count +
                          vm_stat.inactive_count +
                          vm_stat.wire_count) * pagesize;
    natural_t mem_free = vm_stat.free_count * pagesize;
    natural_t mem_total = mem_used + mem_free;

    // do whatever you want with mem_used, mem_free, and mem_total
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. just one question.. i have an iphone 4 and the code above gives me about 300mb of total ram rather than 512.. any idea why?

Comment: Ah, in retrospect it might not be useful for you. It's the amount of memory available to the current process. You'll see the numbers go up and down depending upon the number of processes you have running.

Comment: understood.. is there another way to determine the actual size of the ram?

Comment: @user1526474 There may well be, but I'm not familiar with it. Sorry. But hopefully the above image/photo counting routines help.

Answer (score 3):

Try these. Not guaranteed to work on **non-jailbroken** devices though.

```
- (NSNumber *) totalDiskSpace
{
    NSDictionary *fattributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:NSHomeDirectory() error:nil];
    return [fattributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemSize];
}

- (NSNumber *) freeDiskSpace
{
    NSDictionary *fattributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:NSHomeDirectory() error:nil];
    return [fattributes objectForKey:NSFileSystemFreeSize];
}
```

To count number of files in a directory (including it's sub directories, I've used this *(which isn't the most efficient way)*:

```
-(NSString *)numberOfSongs
{   
    NSString *musicPath = @"/var/mobile/Media/iTunes_Control/Music/"; 
    NSArray *dirs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:musicPath error:nil];
    NSArray *subs = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:musicPath error:nil];

    int totalFiles;
    int subT = [subs count];
    int dirT = [dirs count];
    totalFiles = subT - dirT;

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", totalFiles];
}
```